# Prove that $U_{n+1} + 1 \geqslant \tfrac{3}{4}(U_{n}+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, recurrence-relations

$U_{n}$ is a sequence where $n$ is natural.

$U_{n+1} = \tfrac{U_{n}^{2}+1}{U_{n}-1}$

$-3 \leqslant U_{n} < -1$

And the **question** is: Prove that $U_{n+1} + 1 \geqslant \tfrac{3}{4}(U_{n}+1)$

My **attempt** was:

$U_{n+1} + 1 = \tfrac{U_{n}}{U_{n}-1}(U_{n}+1)$

And $\tfrac{-1}{2} < \tfrac{1}{U_{n}-1} \leqslant \tfrac{-1}{4}$ ... (1)

And $-3 \leqslant U_{n} < -1$ ... (2)

And I wanted to multiply (1) by (2) but the signs are diffrent so I can't do that.

So how I solve it?

Comment: You know that $U_{n}$ is negative, so you could just use the inequality $-U_{n} \le 3$ instead.

Comment: @preferred_anon But in the end I find $U_{n+1} + 1 \geqslant \tfrac{-3}{4}(U_{n}+1)$ which is not what I'm supposed to prove.

Comment: @preferred_anon What if $U_n = -1.1 > -2$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I don't understand your objection. What then?

Comment: @preferred_anon (-1.1)(-0.25) < 0.75

Comment: @preferred_anon Okay so I did like you said, and I found it exactly like I wanted to prove but my question is what if $U_{n}$ was unknown to be positive or negative, like $U_{n}$ is between -2 and 2? What do I do here?

Answer (score 1):

Since $-3 \le U_n < -1$, we have $U_n-1 <0$, then
$$U_{n+1} + 1 - \tfrac{3}{4}(U_{n}+1) = \frac{U_n^2+1}{U_n-1}+1 - \tfrac{3}{4}(U_{n}+1)\\
=\frac{(U_n+1)(U_n+3)}{4(U_n-1)} \ge 0.\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $-3 \le a <-1$

You have to show that $\frac{a^2+1}{a-1}+1 \ge \frac{3}{4}(a+1).$

We have $\frac{a^2+1}{a-1}+1=\frac{a(a+1)}{a-1}.$ thus

$$\frac{a^2+1}{a-1}+1 \ge \frac{3}{4}(a+1) \iff \frac{a(a+1)}{a-1} \ge \frac{3}{4}(a+1).$$

Since $a+1<0$ we derive

$$\frac{a}{a-1} \le \frac{3}{4}.$$

Since $a-1 <0$ we see that

$$a \ge \frac{3}{4}(a-1).$$

This last inequality is equivalent t0 $$a \ge -3.$$